# Better optimized way to search for a string

Tags: c, substring

I have a string which is of the format Contact:

```
<abcde@123.343:5060;gr=xyz123>;+g134,<more_text>
```

I need to extract the content between the opening `<` and closing `>` 
There can be multiple instances of `<` and `>` , but I have to take the content from the pair in which the parameter `gr=` is present (only one occurrence of this).

To solve this what I did was:

```
ptr = strstr(str,"gr=");
if(ptr)
{
   temp1= ptr;
   while(*temp1 && *temp1!='<')
   {
      temp1--;
   }
   strncpy(newstring,temp1,ptr-temp1); //will copy upto start of gr
   temp2 = strstr(ptr,">")
   if(temp2)
     strncat(newstring,ptr,temp2-ptr); // copy remaining string till it finds closing '>'
}
```

It works fine, but I would like to know if there is anyway to avoid the while loop and going backwards?

Comment: Yes, there are other ways to do it but why do you assume that they would be better? One thing you could do is build `newstring` all in one go (from `temp1` to `temp2`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could search for the first occurrence of '<' and '>' and see if 'gr=' falls between them.

```
lt = strchr(ptr,'<');
gt = strchr(ptr,'>');
gr = strstr(ptr,"gr=");
if ( gr > lt && gr < gt) {
    strncat(newstring,lt,gt-lt);
}
```

Comment: Since the search for lt & gt is just one char, you could use strchr which is slightly faster than strstr. Anyway, your solution seems more efficient and simpler than mine. Well done.

Comment: @FabioCeconello, thanks, even the blind squirrel catches a nut sometimes.

Comment: Certainly you want `strstr(ptr,"<");` or `strchr(ptr,'<');` and not `strstr(ptr,'<');`

Comment: @chux What would happen if I wrote strstr(ptr,'<') instead of strstr(ptr,"<") ?

Comment: @CDahn Did you want this in a loop? Because otherwise if gr parameter is not in the first pair of < > this wont work !

Comment: @user1692342 `strstr(ptr,'<')` is bad code.  1) expect compiler warning. 2) If compiles and allowed to run, the `'<'` would be interpreted as a `char *` (`'<'` is a `char`) and certainly cause a seg fault or some undefined behavior.

Comment: @Fabio, I edited to change it to strchr as you and chux pointed out. Definitely more correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can use strcspn to get the offset to the next marker. Your code doesn't have the loop to look for the next instances, but this code does. I assume your loop is outside that, maybe you'll need to adapt a bit.

```
size_t offset = 0, length;
offset = strcspn(str, "<");
while (str[offset] != '\0')
{
  ++offset;
  length = strcspn(str + offset, ">");
  ptr = strstr(str + offset, "gr=");
  if (ptr != NULL && ptr - str < offset + length)
  {
       strncpy(newstring, ptr + offset, length); 
       /* do what you need with newstring here */
  }
  offset = strcspn(str + offset + length + 1, "<");
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But I think @CDahn solution is really simple :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by parsing the string exactly once and not more (unlike other answers here). The code below can handle any substring you give provided the substring doesn't have any repeated characters.

The idea is to copy anything in between any `<` and `>`; while copying look for the substring, if it's not found, then continue until it's found.

```
char *str = "<abcde@123.343:5060;gr=xyz123>;+g134,<more_text>";
char result[MAX_LENGTH];
size_t i = 0, j = 0;
char copying = 0, found = 0;
const char *subs = "gr=";
const int subs_len = 3;
while ((char ch = *str))
{
    if (ch == '<')
       copying = 1;
    else if (ch == '>')
    {
       if (found)
          break;
       else
       {
          copying = 0;
          i = j = 0;
       }
    }
    else if (copying)
    {
       result[i++] = ch;
       if (!found)
       {
          if (ch == subs[j])
          {
             ++j;
             if (j == subs_len)
                found = 1;
          }
          else
          {
             j = (ch == subs[0]) ? 1 : 0;
          }
       }
    }
    ++str;
}
result[i] = '\0';
```